# Regarding associating web roles to contact from Power Pages Portal

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, dynamics-crm-portals

I have to implement the assigning of web roles to the **Contact** from the portal itself.

I have the contact form which has the web role subgrid, on the portal but it's not editable at all even though I am creating proper **Basic Form Metadata** in basic forms.

I have also added proper permissions so that when I add web roles forms on the portal, I can update and create the web roles but I am unable to associate web roles from the subgrid in contact form.

**Note**: Contact and Web role entity do not have any relation and I am also unable to create M2M relation between them.

Is there way so that I can assign web roles from the portal itself which creating a contact or modify them?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot searching here and there, finally I got the problem and the solution as well.

So, I was trying to create relationship between **Contact** and **Web Role** entity which was possible in `Standard Data Model` but since now we have `Enhanced Data Model`, the web role entity is not a standard or custom table instead its a virtual table and hence we can't create the relationship. It's actually is the part of Site Component table.

The actual relationship is between **Contact** and **Site Component** entity.

Here is the reference which I found helpful: https://www.dancingwithcrm.com/web-roles-and-enhanced-data-model/

In **Basic Form Metadata**, we have to create for Contact and Site Component relationship and give proper permissions for Site Component Table.

Also, I was able to create the flow as well, as given in the reference linked above.

Thanks guys if anyone was giving their time for this question.